Path depending on OS
I have a job which will run on both Windows and Linux. The job processes a number of CSV files located at some path. The path in Windows and Linux is obviously defined differently.
I have a 'Get Variables' design component getting the os.name variable, then I have a 'Filter' checking is os.name starts with text "Win" or not. When the OS is identified, then workflow sends to the relevant path or goes to a Dummy output.
The image below shows the starting part of the flow. There is an analogous side which has input from 'Get Variables' and checks that it is not 'Win'.

This is not working though. Any ideas how to work it out?
